# How to manually add description and keywords in php?

Tags: php

This is my php code, and I want to add a manual description and keywords in here?

```js
// define meta tags
$meta_title = $video['video_title'] . ' MyWebsite ';
$video['excerpt'] = (empty($video['excerpt'])) ? $video['video_title'] : $video['excerpt'];
$meta_description = generate_excerpt(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $video['excerpt']), 150) .'...';

$meta_keywords = '';
if(is_array($tags_arr))
foreach($tags_arr as $id => $v)
{
    $meta_keywords .= $v['tag'] . ', ';
}
$meta_keywords = substr($meta_keywords, 0, -2);
// end
```

Comment: What does it mean manuallly?

Comment: so i want directly in php, not from my admin panel, i have do that before but i have forget that now

Comment: so when there is no excerpt it will set manual description right?

Comment: example this part was like this $meta_title = $video['video_title']; and i have add somthing extra in here $meta_title = $video['video_title'] . ' MyWebsite '; like this i want to add discreptions and keywords thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: $meta_description = generate_excerpt(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $video['excerpt']), 150) .'...'; Here i want to add post title and some text extra, and in keyword $meta_keywords = '';  post tiels and somthign extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate your meta to existing meta like with the title, define an array of your meta and concatenate it.

```
<?php
$meta = [
    'title' => 'MyWebsite',
    'description' => 'My description',
    'keywords' => 'My keywords',
];

// define meta tags
$meta_title = $video['video_title'].' '.$meta['title'];
$video['excerpt'] = (empty($video['excerpt'])) ? $video['video_title'] : $video['excerpt'];
$meta_description = generate_excerpt(str_replace('"', '&quot;', $video['excerpt'].' '.$meta['description']), 150).'...';

$meta_keywords = '';
if (is_array($tags_arr)) {
    foreach ($tags_arr as $id => $v) {
        $meta_keywords .= $v['tag'] . ', ';
    }
    $meta_keywords = substr($meta_keywords, 0, -2).' '.$meta['keywords'];
}
```

If you want to replace the meta, then just replace the vars.

```
<?php
$meta = [
    'title' => 'MyWebsite',
    'description' => 'My description',
    'keywords' => 'My keywords',
];

// define meta tags
$meta_title = $video['video_title'].' '.$meta['title'];
$meta_description = $meta['description'];
$meta_keywords = $meta['keywords'];
```